# Determining how many users are using iPad 1 versus iPad 2?

Tags: ios, ipad

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to obtain these statistics. My understanding is that Apple doesn't store this data anywhere on an app by app basis, is that correct?

I'm hoping to find a better way to store it instead of just sending it to a database (if possible)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not make per-app stats available. You can install your own metrics (or use a 3rd party — I used to use Flurry but didn't bother with my next app).

You can estimate based on iPad sales. Wikipedia says over 15M iPad 1 and about 25M iPad 2.

(Personally, unless you're doing something with a camera or GPU-intensive game, I don't think it matters much. There's no difference that affects my apps.)

Comment: Flurry seems to be a great solution. It appears to be nice and lightweight!

Comment: If you estimate based on iPad sales you miss anything unique to your application.  For example if you are the only product of your type to work on the ipad1 you may have a disproportionate number of ipad1 users.   Or if your application really only just barely works on a ipad1 you may have the other kind of disproportionate numbers.    If you can get real numbers they are always better then guesses :-)

Comment: @Stripes Sure, there are always exceptions. If it does matter to you, then do the work of measuring. I decided even Flurry wasn't worth the effort (even though I'd be interested in knowing).

Comment: By the way the guy that does Instapaper has published stats on hardware an OS breakdowns of his user base on his blog.  It looks skewed towards iPads, but it is an interesting set of numbers.  I don't have a long term link to that article, but if you look in 2011 it shoulnt be too hard to find on Marco.org.